# Preselect option dynamically dropdown PHP

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have an array $faecher to create an SELECT Field with options. My problem is that I want to pre-select an option which is saved in variable f_name1.

```
<select> 
    <?php                       
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($faecher); $i++)
            echo "<option" if ($faecher[$i] == f_name1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ">".$faecher[$i]."</option>";
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<option".($faecher[$i] == $f_name1 ? ' selected="selected"' : null).">".$faecher[$i]."</option>";
```

or

```
echo "<option".($faecher[$i] == $f_name1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '').">".$faecher[$i]."</option>";
```

Comment: Why output `null`? Maybe just empty string?

Answer (score 0):

When you'll learn to indent you code, it will be easier:

```
echo "<option"; 
if ($faecher[$i] == f_name1) { 
    echo ' selected="selected"'; 
}
echo ">".$faecher[$i]."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

What is f_name1 here? You should use direct string here. Like below

```
<select> 
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= count($faecher); $i++) { ?>
        <option <?php echo $faecher[$i] == "Matching String" ? "selected" : ""; ?>><?php echo $faecher[$i]; ?></option>     
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```